Which library can I use for machine learning in Rust Solana program? Of course Rust crates!
Sorry for my interrupting.
I have no enough understanding weather it is possible to train  AI model in Solana program or not.
I need some guide in this area.
Thank you.

You get very little compute in a Solana program invocation, up to 1.4 million compute units, which maxes out at 1.4 million BPF instructions. There's also no native support for floating point numbers, so you likely won't get very far. Write a program, and see how far you get!

Thank you. is there any other reasons? For example can I use the Rust crates for AI modeling in Solana program?

It depends on what the crate is doing inside, so I can't tell you for sure. If it's just doing math, you should be ok. Note that you are also limited by what you can do in a program, ie. no file system, no rand, no network calls, and just the BPF instruction set. You can read more at https://solana.com/docs/programs/lang-rust#restrictions
